# /usr/bin/nodejs: no such file or directory

Tags: raspbian, node.js

**Platform:** Raspberry Pi 3

**SO:** Raspbian

I would like to try nodejs in my raspberry. I tried to install npm packages via terminal and I got the next errors.

**Command**

`sudo npm install -g n`

**Errors**

`./npm: bad interpreter: /usr/bin/nodejs: no such file or directory`

**Install nodejs**

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

**Terminal output**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

**Install npm**

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

**Terminal output**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
npm is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Do you already download package nodejs? It obvious that you must download and install nodejs before using npm

Comment: Maybe this link could help http://goo.gl/01FUSO

Answer (score 2):

As xdhe points out you need two packages (I am surprised `npm` did not include node as a dependency, but anyway...)

```
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo apt install npm
```

Comment: I have update the information about the error. I have already installed npm and node.